# building static OpenSSL library on Windows

Tags: openssl

I am building the OpenSSL as a static library, but the linking fails. I am using the following commands:

`perl Configure VC-WIN64A no-shared
nmake`

The linking fails with unresolved externals (libapps.lin, libssl.lib, ...)
Also there was warning:

`LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library`

but nmake doesn't accept the /NODEFAULTLIB argument.

Does anybody has any suggestion how to build OpenSSL as a static library on Windows?

I followed the docs in the OpenSSL folder and the result of it are commands I have used, but which don't work.

As a note, I can created dynamic libraries just fine.

Comment: What version of OpenSSL are you using? Did you run "nmake clean" between building the dynamic verison, and building the static version?

Comment: OpenSSL 1.1.1c. I didn't run nmake clean. I think this could be an issue. I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that runs into this problem with openssl 3.2.1 (latest version as of writing this), I shared a project here that contains the .bat files that I use for building static libssl & libcrypto against a statically linked runtime:

https://github.com/tfarthing/openssl-windows-static

The trick for me was:

- `set CPPFLAGS=/MT` before running the configuration
- use the `no-shared` configuration parameter

You can see this done in the `build.bat` file.
The `fetch.bat` file just demonstrates automated fetching of the dependencies.  It was working when I last tried but will need some updating as time goes by.